# How does Javascript 'includes' method work when passing an object to array of objects

Tags: javascript

Does includes method consider references too.

Eg:

```
let temp1 = [{a:5,b:3},{a:10,b:10}]
temp1.includes(temp1[0]) 
//returns true
```

```
let obj = {...temp1[0]}
temp1.includes(obj)
//returns false
```

Can someone please explain how `includes` method is working in this context

Comment: They must be _the exact same object_. `obj === temp1[0] // false`

Comment: I understand they are not the same object but how is includes method working when passing object having multiple key-value pairs.

Comment: In the first example, you are asking if `temp1` contains an object, this object comes from `temp1` so it's true. It's not comparing values or keys.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `temp1[0]` you are comparing it with the exact same object, which is its first item, so it will return `true`.

When you uses the spread operator (`...temp1`) you are cloning the object, so when you compare both objects they won't be the exact same objects, and it will return `false`.

Comment: includes compares values in an array, so if we pass objects which has keys  does it compare key-value pairs. I wanted to know how includes work when objects are passed.

Comment: @bhasuru, no, it doesn't compare key-values, it compares between the *address* of the object in memory.